# Unable to retrieve properties with exposeContextBeansAsAttributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl

currently using spring 'exposedContextBeanNames' to allow me to display properties in my view but havign issues with some properties that contain a ".".

My xml is setup as

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list><value>classpath:servers.properties</value> </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> 
    <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/> 
    <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
        <list>  
            <value>properties</value> 
        </list>
    </property>  
</bean>
```

My "servers.properties" has a number of values

```
value1=this is the first value
value.value1=this is my second value
```

In my JSP

```
${properties.value1}
```

will display "this is the first value" as expected but

```
${properties.value.value1}
```

does not work. I'm hoping someone may be able to help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `${ properties['value.value1'] }`.

Comment: would you know if its possible to do the same if my properties file looked like this; value1=${my.env.value} where its picking up the envirnoment value. if I try to print this value I get the string "${my.env.value}" in place of the env value.